What is the effect of WEP and GPO if I worked as a teacher?
If person A chooses not to work (for pay that is, let's use the term "home maker" for this person "not working"), and is married to a significant wage earner, at retirement this person can collect 1/2 their spouse's benefit in addition to what the spouse is already collecting.
Now let's say person B works as a teacher for 10 years, paying into a retirement plan but not Social Security. In this example, person B will get 1000/mo from their government pension. Social Security didn't get any more or less put into the system by person B than by person A.
At retirement, person B tries to also collect 1/2 their spouse's social security benefit, but it gets reduced by 1/2 of their pension amount, or $500/mo in this example, due to "WEP" or “Windfall Elimination Provision”. If the spouse passes away, the Social Security benefit can get reduced by 2/3 of the pension, or $666/mo., based on "GPO" or “Government Pension Offset”.
How does this make sense? I fail to see the logic.

I'm not sure this is a personal finance question.  Lots of programs have scenarios where they appear to be unfair because they are trying to balance multiple political objectives.  In this case, spousal benefits for the homemaker exist to ensure that the wife who never worked isn't destitute if the primary earner dies in retirement.  SS benefits to those that have other pensions are reduced because those individuals do have other income sources.  How to balance those out is a politics question not a personal finance question.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a politics question not a personal finance question.

@JustinCave ". . . destitute if the primary earner dies in retirement." Not really. Spousal benefits for the current spouse at 50% are only during the life of the primary earner. Upon death, survivor benefits take over, amounting to the full amount that the deceased was getting at time of death, including delayed retirement credits if any. This can be more than double the spousal benefit. Mr primary earner better watch his Ps and Qs! See 20 CFR § 404.313(e)(1).

The government pension effectively replaces Social Security for those workers. They are exempt from paying into Social Security, but unlike person A who doesn't work for pay (i.e. would never pay into Social Security because there's no income), person B would have paid into Social Security if not for that exception.
Social Security's spousal benefit is intended to allow a low/non-earning spouse to have benefits during their spouse's retirement. It's not meant to benefit someone who worked and has a pension, but whose Social Security benefit is lower than their spouse's because they didn't have to pay into Social Security.
